# Check button in Google Spreadsheets specific for each user

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation, google-drive-sharing

I have a Google Spreadsheet with different tasks. I want to implement a check button in the following way:

My intention is that the users can't edit the spreadsheet but they have to be able to use the check button at each task. The difficult part is that it is the intention that these check buttons are user specific. So if one user checks or unchecks a button this doesn't change the check buttons of the other users. Further, it is the intention that when a user closes the spreadsheets and opens it the next day the same buttons have to be checked as when he closed the spreadsheet.

The farthest I got is to make checkboxes that only I as the creator of the spreadsheet can edit. Does anybody have an idea how I could make this or if it is even possible to make?

Comment: See [Protect, hide, and edit sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?hl=en)

Comment: This shows how i can let them edit only the check buttons, but main issue is still that it is not user specific. If i understand it correctly in this way if someone checks a check button, that button will be checked for all users

Comment: This question was bumped by Community User. It has been bumped 22 times. It already got two answers, but none of them have got a single vote or a single comment. I assume it's fair to assume that the question lacks enough details. Please clarify what you are looking for as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a checkbox to be user specific, meaning that each user see different value (checked/unchecked), then you should use a different sheet for each user or to use a Menu/Dialog/Sidebar/Web App together with the Properties Service of Google Apps Script to set/get user properties.

Answer (score -1):

If you have for example a list of people and next to them you have a checkbox column, then you can set every checkbox to be editable by a specified person you set (such person needs to have a google account) and then all other cells in your sheet just lockdown. a lot of setups but it can be done.

Another possibility is to give away a sheet to every person and then have a master sheet that will bring all data from slave sheets. Less secure, but more flexible solution, because you can have rebels which don't have a Google account.